# Task wrap a synchronisation process isn't awaited

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await

My application WPF MVVM loads the files (almost 10000 files) in a folder.
`ProgressExplorerValue` is the value of a progress bar.

```
public async Task ChargeFolderAsync()
{
    IsTaskConversionFinish = false;
    var rs = await Task.Run(() => LoadEntriesInFolder());
    IsTaskConversionFinish = true;
    ProgressExplorerValue = 0;
}

public IEnumerable<Record> LoadEntriesInFolder()
 {
     var rs = new List<Record>();
     var di = new DirectoryInfo(InitPath).EnumerateFiles();
     double factorPercent = di.Count() == 0 ? 0 : 100d / di.Count();            

     foreach (var file in di)
     {
         Record rc = new Record()
         {
             MetaName = file.Name,
             MetaPath = file.FullName
         };
         rs.Add(rc);
         ProgressExplorerValue += factorPercent;
     }
     return rs;
 }
```

The task isn't awaited at the line `await Task.Run(() => LoadEntriesInFolder());`. When I debug, it jumps from this line to next line without a break even that the method `LoadEntriesInFolder` hasn't yet completed.

Comment: Add `ToList()` after `EnumerateFiles()`. This might be enumeration problem

Comment: The OP seems to be iterating over `di` in the `LoadEntriesInFolder()` method.

Comment: @AntoineV: Are you saying that no records are added to `rs`? Does `InitPath` contain anything?

Comment: @mm8 absolute sure the InitPath correct with a lot of files inside it

Comment: @AntoineV: Did you step through `LoadEntriesInFolder()` in the debugger? Or how do you know that it doesn't return before `IsTaskConversionFinish` is set to `true` in `ChargeFolderAsync()`?

Answer (score 0):

How do you call your ChargeFolderAsync method? I called it in program.cs like below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new FileLoader().ChargeFolderAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And added console log in your async method.

```
Console.WriteLine(ProgressExplorerValue);
```

It gave this output.

[image]

I think this is your desired output.

Answer (score -5):

When doing
`await Task.Run(() => LoadEntriesInFolder());`
 your awaiting for the return value of the `Run();` method and not until the Task is finished.
try
    `Task.Run(() => LoadEntriesInFolder()).Wait();`

Comment: Not tested but I think it changes nothing